# How create utctime query from model on yesod?

Tags: sql, time, utc, yesod

Hi everyone my question is about how can I create a query on Yesod from my database for get only the instance which satisfy the condition by UTCtime.

My model is this:

```
Post
    name Text
    content Text
    date UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    deriving Show
```

And I want a query which I can extract only the post which satisfy a date whit the year 2014, for example. I suppose my handler for the query must look something similar like this:

```
getYearR :: Integer -> Handler Html
getYearR year = do
    posts <- runDB $ selectList [*With some code here about the date and year*] [Desc PostDate]
    defaultLayout $ do
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Blog"
        $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

Maybe the solution is create a raw sql query, but I think that is not a right solution.

Thanks for your time and I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
let date = fromGregorian 2014 1 1
    time = timeOfDayToTime $ TimeOfDay 0 0 0
posts <- runDB $ selectList [PostDate >. UTCTime date time] [Desc PostDate]
```

I'm not aware of any function in Persistent that can do this. Raw SQL query will also work.